# WordPress not remembering old slugs for pages

Tags: permalinks, redirect, slug

I have several WordPress sites working under different domains, but hosted on the same server.

I noticed that most of them will remember the old slug if changed. So it redirects to the new one if accessed. However, some of them wont do that despite being the same WordPress version.

Why is that? How can I fix it?

> Note: I just noticed the only difference between the sites that remember and those that wont is that, for the former I have posts whereas for the latter I have fixed pages.

Comment: I just noticed the only difference between the sites that remember and those that wont is that for the former I have posts whereas for the latter I have fixed pages.

Answer (score 3):

WordPress keeps track of post slug change with `wp_check_for_changed_slugs()` function. The old slugs are saved in `wp_postmeta` table with `_wp_old_slug` `meta_key` and later redirects to current URL with `wp_old_slug_redirect()` function.

That's why even after changing a post's slug, you get redirected to the correct post.

However, WordPress doesn't do this by default with pages (or any hierarchical posts).

It's still possible to change this behaviour by hooking into `post_updated` action and replicate `wp_check_for_changed_slugs()` function for pages (or any hierarchical posts) and then implementing the redirect logic using `old_slug_redirect_url` hook.

However, this is not recommended.

The main reason is: pages may have multiple levels (hierarchical). For example, a child page can be `page_a/child-1` and another child page `page_a/child-2` (there can be many more, with multiple levels).

Now, changing `page_a` slug affects both `child-1` and `child-2` pages. So to implement this properly, while visiting both `child-1` and `child-2`, WordPress will have to check for first `child-1` or `child-2` slug change, and then `page_a` parent slug change. This sort of multi level checks will slow down WordPress for hierarchical posts or pages.

You'll find a similar discussion in [WordPress.org support](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/_wp_old_slug-not-created-for-pages-2/).

If you still need this, it's better to use a redirect plugin and manually add the redirect for pages with old permalinks.

Comment: If you need redirection for hierarchial posts when their slug change, then [Slim SEO](https://wpslimseo.com) is a good plugin that offers this functionality.